# Received fatal alert: bad_record_mac when Git Push with netbeans 8

Tags: java, git, spring-mvc, netbeans, bitbucket

Hey i am using Netbeans 8, SpringMVC, Java, Oracle and my project run fine but when i try to make git push then alert me with Received

> Git Command Returned with the following error: https://ftoro%40medianet.com.ve@bitbucket.org/Fideltoro/svservicios:  Received fatal alert: bad_record_mac

need help please

i check my credentials and the url

actually when i make Git Pull he works fine, the problem is with push only

Comment: can you try with git bash. There is a simple command. `git push origin master` or use `git push origin your_branch_name` if you are on some branch

Comment: @Shahzeb Thanks bro, Push Works Fine with git bash. i open git Bash, move into my project directory and set the command >> git push origin << and Muchas Gracias

Comment: Glad, it helped.

Comment: hey Happy new Year!  the full solution is update git on my computer to the last version

Answer (score 0):

Check if the error persists over time, as this error is described in "[The case of the “Page can’t be displayed” intermittent selenium test](https://engineering.imvu.com/author/imvuengineering/)" ans an SSL fatal error during SSL handshake.

Check also if you can upgrade to the latest Git possible, to see if the error was fixed (in in this [bug issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/support-forum/issues/1553))

Comment: thanks for the help bro,  i solve with git bash and before that i delete and set again the url to my repository in netbeans